# What is this hypothesis testing bidirectional inequality symbol called?

Tags: probability, inequality, hypothesis-testing

I can't for the life of me find what this symbol is called. Bonus points if you can tell me how to write it in LaTeX. It's fairly obvious what it means but I cannot find any combination of words to induce Google into finding other instances of this symbol.

[image]

Comment: `\gtrless` is $\gtrless$. I used http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Amazing, that's such a helpful website had no idea that existed. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept it